# Closing browser without user interaction in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a scenario where I need to open a browser to remove user cookies for logging out. So the process is:

1. Open browser (Chrome CustomTab or SFSafariView depending on OS) and point it towards my URL to delete cookies.
2. Send the user back to the mobile app login screen.

Where I'm having an issue is step 2. How do I go about closing/minimizing the browser without requiring user interaction? The only thing I have found so far is to run `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();` which closes the entire app, but I have seen comments online that doing this might cause the app to get rejected by Google and/or Apple.

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: I think you will need to tap into the Navigating/Navigated property of a webview, probably the latter so that when it  finished navigating where it needed to, then you can present the needed page

Answer (score 0):

You can put `SFSafariViewController` inside the navigation controller and then you can dismiss the navigation controller. That's for iOS assuming that you already know when to call this code, just don't know how. For Android... no idea for now, probably you should ask it as a separate question not too many people are experts both for Android and iOS...